# In mysql how do I query at, above, and below values for each score across multiple tests? Bonus points if there is calculated percentile rankings

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, pivot-table

tbl Scores: (csv; i dont know how to format a table schema on here)

```
test_id, student_id, score   
1, 1, 75  
1, 2, 84  
1, 3, 60  
2, 1, 82  
1, 4, 90  
1, 5, 75  
2, 2, 70  
2, 3, 90  
2, 5, 76
```

What I need to do is, for each test at each score, calculate the number of students at that score and then figure out what percentile that score is for each test.

I've used a query to successfully count number of students by each score:

```
SELECT test_id, score, COUNT(student_id) as num_students FROM Scores GROUP BY test_id, score
```

At this point I am trying to get the #at, #below, and #above for each score on each test so that I can try to calculate percentile for each.

Would this be some kind of pivot table?

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you need to do this with a correlated subquery.  Here is an example for the number of students below:

```
 SELECT test_id, score, COUNT(student_id) as num_students,
        (select count(*) from scores s2 where s2.test_id = s.test_id and s2.score < s.score
        ) as below
 FROM Scores s
 GROUP BY test_id, score
```

Comment: In reality this is on about 1 million records for ~300 test for ~4k unique scores. This is a for reports and is accessed only a few times a year.  This seems like a pretty expensive query, almost akin to brute forcing in php (though def simpler in sql). For learning sake, is there a faster way of going about this? THANKS

Comment: Could you expand on why there needs to be a correlated subquery?

Comment: @JakubKania . . . Because MySQL does not offer any other mechanism for doing cumulative sums.  You can express the same idea with a non-equijoin, but that is essentially equivalent.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff btw this gets me to the next step, thanks. On my full dataset I can probably go to lunch while I run this, but I will be able to output the necessary data in one query!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have to be correlated but it will probably perform worse due to cross join and distinct <s>I'm not sure will it perform better or worse</s>:

```
SELECT s.test_id, 
       s.score, 
       Count(DISTINCT s.student_id) AS num_students, 
       Count(DISTINCT z.student_id) AS below 
FROM   scores s 
       LEFT JOIN scores z 
              ON s.test_id = z.test_id 
                 AND s.score > z.score 
GROUP  BY s.test_id, 
          s.score 
ORDER  BY s.test_id, 
          s.score;
```

Y
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fd824/13